# string comparison inside if condition malfunctioning

Tags: c, string, gcc

I tried to program in C but was not sucessful. I have a simple source code and I need to match multiple letters in `if (char)`. It's displaying the following error message (in linux terminal using gcc):

> main.c: In function `main': main.c:16:23: warning: character constant
>   too long for its type         [enabled   by default]
>
> if (firstName[20] == 'Vojta'){

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[40];
    char password[20];
    char confpasswd[20];
    int age;

    printf("Please write your first and last name:");
    scanf("%s%s", firstName, lastName);
    printf("%s %s:\n", firstName, lastName);

    if (firstName[20] == 'Vojta'){
        printf("\ncool\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'Vojta'` is a multi-character string constant; it's of type `int` with an implementation-defined value. This is an obscure feature of the C language. I've seen it misused far more often than I've seen it used correctly.

Comment: And `firstName[20]` does not refer to the entire 20-element array; it refers to element 20 of the array, an object of type `char`. Since the array only has elements 0 through 19, `firstName[20]` doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Point 1**

Use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to compare *strings*.

**Point 2**

Change

```
scanf("%s%s", firstName, lastName);
```

to

```
scanf("%19s %39s", firstName, lastName);
```

and **do** check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure sucess. However, it's better if you use two `scanf()` seperately to take two inputs, that will be *less* error prone.

Also, as a suggestion , you can read about [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) for a how-to read a whole line as input and *tokenize* the required part.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this line:

```
if (firstName[20] == 'Vojta'){
```

`firstName` is an array and its value was set via the `scanf()`. Therefore, first name will contain a terminating NULL char (`'\0'`).
Therefore, the contents of `firstName`, if the user entered `'Vojta'`
would be `'V'`, `'o'`, `'j'`, `'t'`, `'a'`, `'\0'` followed by 14 garbage characters.

Because of the trailing `'\0'` (which was inserted by the `scanf()`) the contents of `firstName` is a valid string.

The best way to compare the contents of `firstName` with some string literal, is to compare it to a string literal, using the function `strcmp()`.

Note: the current code is comparing the (offset) 20 position in `firstName` (which is outside the bounds of the array and therefore results in undefined behaviour).

Here is an example of the right way to make a string comparison:

```
if( 0 == strcmp( firstName, "Vojta" ) )
```

Do notice the double quote marks (`"`) around the string literal.

Those double quote marks make it a string literal rather than just a bunch of characters that the compiler will evaluate to an 'int' value.

Note: individual characters can be represented by using single quote marks around each character as in: `'V'`, `'o'`, `'j'`, `'t'`, `'a'`.

The `strcmp()` function

1. returns `< 0` if the first parameter (contents of `firstName`) comes before (alphabetically) the second parameter.
2. returns `> 0` if the first parameter (contents of `firstName`) comes after (alphabetically) the second parameter.
3. returns `0` if the first parameter matches the second parameter.

Comment: Detail: "returns -1 if the first parameter ..." is really "returns an `int` less than 0  if the first parameter ..."